# Executing Body inside an async task

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

This has been driving me insane, maybe someone's hit this already.. I have a composite activity that does some I/O. Its multiple other activities, and i really dont care about the outcome in my main flow. I thought I could get away with the really easy approach of building a codeactivity with a designer on it that supports an itemcontainer, drop my fire and forget workflow in there, and fire that async. Seems i can't, as asynccodeactivity doesn't support child activites -- incidentally, anyone know why this is?

Anyway, is there any way to build a sequence-style activity where that sequence will just hum along on a separate thread for however long it takes (30-60 sec in this case) while my main flow goes about its business?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there's no way to place child activities inside asynchronous activities. You can only have code activities, using [AsyncCodeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.asynccodeactivity.aspx) and [AsyncCodeActivity(Of TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780675.aspx).

Anyway, why don't you use [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.parallel.aspx)? Execute the asynchronous code activity within one branch and the rest of the workflow within another branch.

Comment: Really, im trying to get around something different.. I have a receive activity, followed by a send activity which returns back the workflow id for tracking. After that, in the same sequence, i have my long-running stuff. For some reason, it seems the send doesn't actually send the message back (or at least doesn't unblock the client app) until the rest of the sequence is complete. What I really need is to get that ID back immediately, and let the rest of it run.. Async was my approach to that, im open to other suggestions.. Cant really do parallel, the receive gets variables i need..

Comment: Are you replying two times? One with the workflowInstanceId and another at the end of the sequence? Either way, if you aren't receiving the first message with the workflowInstanceId, something is wrong with that particular part of the workflow.

Comment: I have a parallel activity, inside that, two sequences, each sequence has; 1. Receive (diff. activity each) 2. Reply 3. Delay (60sec). I only get the call back after 60 sec..

Comment: If that's your workflow, there's nothing wrong with it. You should receive both messages and the Delay continues to work at service side. Maybe something wrong with your client or a problem with messages contracts, can't really tell without some kind of exception message.

Comment: oddly enough, theres not even a real contract to speak off, just taking in an int argument and returning an int variable. No exceptions get thrown, nothing. If I swap the delay to a codeactivity that does thread.sleep(5000) and time the invokations, they all take 5000-7000ms. Reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WF4Extensions.aspx im wondering if i need to do a persist on the sendresponse? Does it matter that this is a xamlx service and not just a WF in a host?